# return a boolean using Postgres

Tags: postgresql

How to return a boolean true/false instead of t/f from a field of string type in Postgres.

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN status = 'active' THEN true ELSE false END)::boolean AS status 
FROM table;
```

Comment: Just use `1` and `0` values.

Comment: @sagi: `1` and `0` aren't boolean values, those are numbers

Answer (score 3):

`t` and `f` is just how `psql` prints booleans, it shouldn't be important. Also, you can simplify your query as follows:

```
SELECT status = 'active' AS status FROM table;
```

If you really want to get text for the column `status`, do the following:

```
SELECT (status = 'active')::text AS status FROM table;
```

If you want to get a number instead (0 for false, 1 for true), do this:

```
SELECT (status = 'active')::integer AS status FROM table;
```

Comment: the result of the query is important to me because I use it in my php code with a library, the result must be true / false without double quotes

Comment: @Nawalel I haven't use the PHP bindings of postgres but it should handle the first query correctly. If it doesn't try the third one, which converts the booleans to 0/1.